# Retrieving many images from mysql automatically by an echo and enlarging them on click

Tags: php, mysql, image, zooming, display

I have a PhP shopping cart for autoparts and I need to be able to enlarge the retrieved image upon clicking on it. The problem is I can't manually assign an ID to every picture because I'm echoing them from the database.

I've tried assigning one ID/class to all the pictures that get retrieved and enlarge them on click using the JS function but can't get it working.

````
    $items_array = $db_controller->runQuery("SELECT * FROM mystuff ORDER BY ID ASC");
    if (!empty($items_array)) { 
        foreach($items_array as $key=>$value){
    ?>

            <div class="DisplayCartItems">

            <form method="post" action="?action=add&mscode=<?php echo $product_array[$key]["mscode"]; ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $product_array[$key]["msimage"]; ?>" class="imgcartdisplay" align="alignnone"/> /* Right here I need some help */
            <div class="lif"><strong>Category:</strong> <?php echo $product_array[$key]["mscategory"]; ?></div>
            <div class="lif"><strong>Category №:</strong> <?php echo $product_array[$key]["mscatnum"]; ?></div>
            <div class="lif"><strong>Stock №:</strong> <?php echo $product_array[$key]["msnomer"]; ?></div> 
            <div class="lif"><strong>Mark:</strong> <?php echo $product_array[$key]["msmark"]; ?></div>
            <div class="lif"><strong>Model:</strong> <?php echo $product_array[$key]["msmodel"]; ?></div>
            <div class="lif"><strong>Year:</strong> <?php echo $product_array[$key]["msyear"]; ?></div>
            <div class="lif"><strong>Price:</strong> <?php echo "$".$product_array[$key]["msprice"]; ?></div>
            <div style="text-align:center"><input type="number" name="oap" placeholder="Offer a price:"></div>
            <br class="">

            <div class="cartan">
                Quantity: <input type="text" class="product-quantity" name="quantity" value="1" size="2" />

                <br class="">
                <input type="submit" onclick="AddCartAlert()" value="Add to cart" /></div>

    </form>
                </div>
    <?php
        }
    }
    ?>```

I think if I can somehow assign an ID or class name for every picture that get displayed from the MySql and onclick change it's width/height, that'd do the job.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have correctly understood:

you should replace this:

```
<img src="<?php echo $product_array[$key]["msimage"]; ?>" class="imgcartdisplay" align="alignnone"/> /* Right here I need some help */
```

with:

```
<a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $product_array[$key]["msimage"]; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product_array[$key]["msimage"]; ?>" class="imgcartdisplay" align="alignnone"/></a>
```

for opening the image in another tab.

Or... if you mean something like this https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#examples you have to use javascript (for example: `<a href="images/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My caption">Image #1</a>`)

In your case something like this: (of course you need to add lightbox script: https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#getting-started)

```
<a data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My caption" href="<?php echo $product_array[$key]["msimage"]; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product_array[$key]["msimage"]; ?>" class="imgcartdisplay" align="alignnone"/></a>
```

Comment: Ooh finally, thank you very much ;]
I will just have to edit a lil bit lightbox's script and it will look amazing.

Comment: I'm glad to help, buddy!